# rails params.merge in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a URL parameter in a link_to block.

The code currently `<%= link_to "Submit", :action => 'renderChart', :class => "btn", :remote => true, :params => params.merge(:limit => 5) %>`

but this gives me an error.

It adds the :class and :action into the url parameter, not just the :limit. Why?

EDIT:

I add other URL params from another link that looks like this

```
link_to "Toggle Sort Direction",:action => 'renderChart', :remote => true, :params => {:sort => "desc"}
```

so when the user clicks the other link I want to add the limit to the url params and keep the sort params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get a solution myself.

If I very simply do this: `:params => {:limit => ..., :sort => params[:sort]}` i get exactly what I need. If there is a sort param it keeps it the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<%= link_to "Submit",{ :action => 'renderChart', :remote => true, :limit => 5, :sort => "desc"}, :class => "btn" %>
```

Separate out the `html_options`: `class` is an html_option so pass it last.

Refer to **[link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)** documentation.

**UPDATE**

As per the OP's concern in EDIT section of Question:

> I add other URL params from another link that looks like this
>
> ```
> link_to "Toggle Sort Direction",:action => 'renderChart', :remote => true, :params => {:sort => "desc"}
> ```

params `:sort => "desc"` are for `Toggle Sort Direction` link and they cannot be connected to the `Submit` link. When you click on a particular link, params specified in the link would be added to the `params` hash. So, if you need to pass `:sort => "desc"` as params upon clicking on `Submit` link then specify them **explicitly** as shown in my answer above.

Comment: this overwrites the existing URL params though. I want to add :limit to existing url params

Comment: How exactly are you adding other params to the URL?

Comment: Those params are for `Toggle Sort Direction` link, you are not clicking on that so those params will not be added to the params hash anyways. If you need to pass them as well in your hash when you click on `Submit` button then pass them explicitly for this link as well.

Comment: @Killerpixler why are you downvoting answers for people trying to help you?

Comment: @Killerpixler More detail explanation added to clarify your concern on the way params hash is created. Also, if you have down voted me because of your insufficient knowledge about the `link_to` and how `params` works then its wrong. We are here to help you.

Comment: I am not downvoting anything. I would never do that. Your answer still doesn't help me maintain current params hashs though. Essentially if the :sort is desc leave it desc, if it is asc make it asc

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly separate the hashes:

```
<%= link_to "Submit", { :action => 'renderChart', :class => "btn", :remote => true }, params.merge(:limit => 5) %>
```

Take the `link_to` out and you have an implicit hash (key-value pairs) and Ruby is smart enough to know you want a hash:

```
:action => 'renderChart', :class => "btn", :remote => true, params.merge(:limit => 5)
```

But that last thing - that's not a key-value pair - it's a hash. So really, you have this:

```
{ :action => 'renderChart', :class => "btn", :remote => true, { ... } }
```

If you take Rails out of the mix:

```
{ x: 'value', {} }
```

And that's simply not a valid Hash :)

Comment: Well, the OP changed the question: http://cl.ly/image/220X3f050o2Y/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-28%20at%2012.50.58%20PM.png. This was the right answer to the original question.

Comment: I tried that but now I only get the `class=btn` as a url param

Comment: `:class => "btn"` is an html_option, you are passing it incorrectly. You are mixing the options.