# Rails:: param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do an *add-to-favorite* option to the items. Which allows the user to add a specific item to the list of favorite. But I get this error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: favorite
```

The create method in the favorite controller:

```
def create
@favorite = Favorite.new(params.require(:favorite).permit(:item_id, :user_id ))
if @favorite.save
  redirect_to @favorite
   flash[:notice] = 'Favorite was successfully created.' 
else
  render 'new'
end
end
```

The view for the item show:

```
<%= link_to 'Add to favorites', {:controller => "favorites", 
                   :action => "create", 
                   :item_id => @item.id, 
                   :user_id => current_user.id},
                   :method => "post" %>
```

Request (Parameters):

```
{ "_method"=>"post", "authenticity_token"=>"Wz1eGNw/3GH9t+aOquT/hu1F27zBSqAx6K6igxoc2VI=", "item_id"=>"27",  "user_id"=>"10"}
```

URL:

```
/favorites?item_id=27&user_id=10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at docs for [ActionController#permit](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) it looks like the params need to be nested under favorite:

```
(favorite: { item_id: 1, user_id: 1 })
```

When using rails form helpers like form_for this nesting would be done automatically but because you are manually passing the params in with `link_to` item_id and user_id would be nested straight under params.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718554/rails-params-merge-in-link-to) explains how you can merge your `link_to` arguments into the params hash. Alternatively you could merge them in the controller, before the `params.require` call.

Comment: I used this: @favorite = Favorite.new(params.require(:favorite).permit(favorite: [:item_id, :user_id])). I get the same error msg. And if I remove the require it get saved as nil.

Comment: and oh I tried this "<%= link_to 'Add to favorites', {:controller => "favorites", :action => "create",  :params => {:item_id => @item.id, :user_id => current_user.id } }, :method => "post" %>" But I got "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" it seems that I'm sending a arguments while I'm not suppose to. Idk, I'm confused.

Comment: I think you just need to change the way you are passing params into `link_to`. Try something like `<%= link_to 'Add to favorites', {:controller => "favorites", :action => "create", :params => params.merge({:favorite => {:item_id => @item.id, :user_id => current_user.id }})} %>`. So you are merging your new params into the main params hash and correctly nesting under `favorite`